# How to avoid triggering build if there is a local NuGet package in project dependencies in Azure DevOps

Tags: .net, azure-devops, nuget-package

I am new to Azure DevOps, we use Azure DevOps pipelines in our projects. When we have a pull request for a branch that is using a local NuGet package from another project, the build will fail until we bump up that package, which is resource consuming.

Is there a way to check the content of .Net project dependencies and avoid triggering the build if some local NuGet package is there (considering that we have some custom naming for local packages)? I read about [conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) but couldn't find something specific that can do what I need.

Answer (score 1):

> How to avoid triggering build if there is a local NuGet package in project dependencies in Azure DevOps

I am afraid there is no such a way to avoid triggering build if there is a local NuGet package in project dependencies in Azure DevOps.

That is because there is no such [predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to check if there is a local NuGet package in project dependencies.

even though we could devlop some scripts to check if there is a local NuGet package in project dependencies, but this scripts itself still need to be executed.

Besides, there is another challenge is that if we use the some local NuGet package, there is no more efficient way to do this than to go through the common resources for each package, which is an extra overhead for projects with a large number of packages.